# Communication between components of the same level

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing an application using moviedb api. The main part of the application is over. I am using React Router. I want to transfer the movies to a component named my favorite movies. But in the component hierarchy movie, navbar, favouriteFilms, PersonInfo components are at the same level.

When click on the Add to Favorites button, it is necessary to transfer from the movie component to my favorite movies component. How can I do that ?

I did not discard the blocks of code because they are too long, it will be enough if you tell the algorithm and how I can do it.

Live version of my app: https://alcnuvr-react-movie-app.netlify.app/

Thank you from now.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. We cannot see your code and can offer little advice until we do.

Comment: Hard to give concrete solutions without seeing any of your code - but the standard way to communicate between sibling components is to have the relevant shared state in the parent, and pass both it and the relevant event handler functions down as props. There's a good extended example in the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: You should probably do more reading on React.  This kind of thing is the first thing that they talk about as something that you should change your way of thinking about.  Where generally you try to move "state" higher up in the rendering tree and pass "props' down, and that there is generally a big advantage to planning this organization early on when you design your components.

Comment: in general, the answer to communication between components is https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @user120242 yeah, you are right. It would have been right for me to plan ahead.  I will search. Thanks for answer

Comment: @RobinZigmond 
Normally, I send the movie id through the url and I am showing the component it contains with link to. I'm a little confused for the situation I want. But I will do a more detailed research on the advice of other friends. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea of sharing state between sibling components is lifting the state up.

If you have component B and component C which are siblings and nested inside component A the easiest approach is to have the state live inside component A and passing it down to B and C.

When your App becomes more complex and the component hierarchy is deep, It easier to use a solution to simplify the "prop drilling" (meaning passing the state down the component tree).

In basic cases you can use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to achieve this behaviour.
Alternatives will be libraries such [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html).
When the state is server state it might be useful to consider solutions such as [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query), [swr](https://swr.now.sh/),or [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta) apollo (if the api is a graphql api)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think it makes more sense now to do research about React Context and move it to this point.

Comment: sounds good. A good thing to do after getting some understanding of react context is to combine context with hooks. It is a very useful pattern. here is an example and explanation: 

https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c

Comment: Thanks, I already started to research :)

Answer (score -1):

The solution for your problem is Redux. It's a library that help you to save all your application state in a single object called store, and you can access this object from all your components.

[Docs here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

Comment: Redux is certainly helpful, particularly for complex state which has to be shared across many components. But we don't know if it's the best solution for the OP, and simply recommending a library with no further details is not really an appropriate answer imo.

Comment: I could use redux, but I didn't. I know that already. I'm just asking what can I do for my current situation.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I made a suggestion based on the little informations provided by the author(no code, not specifying the routing library used), with many components with the same level on hierarchy and communicating data I think redux is the best solution imo